# AutoStart with user different than pi

Tags: raspbian-jessie, lxde

So, I'm trying to autostart an app at login, by running a script. Config: no desktop (Raspberry Pi 3B, Jessie). I managed to do it using "pi" user without any trouble. This is my autostart file:

`/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`:

```
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@point-rpi
@lxterminal -e ~/script.sh
```

Now, I've created a new sudo user "myUser" (same groups as "pi"). I'm trying to use the exact same autostart file, `/home/myUser/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`, and it does not execute my script. The only way I managed to execute it is changing

```
@lxterminal -e ~/script.sh
```

for

```
@lxterminal -e /home/myUser/script.sh
```

The thing is that I don't want my autostart file to be username dependant, that's why I used `~/script.sh`.

Note:

```
@lxterminal -e script.sh   --> Doesn't work either.
```

If I run `~/script.sh` or `./script.sh` from console (user: myUser) it runs correctly.

`script.sh` is located at `/home/myUser/`
and at `/home/pi/`

What am I not getting here?

Comment: Well… @lxterminal -e ./script.sh did the trick…. But I still don't understand why ~/script.h didn´t work! Greetings!

Comment: What user are you running it as? Is the file in that user's home directory?This isn't really a Pi related question, this is more Unix&Linux usage.

Comment: myUser is auto booting, and the file is at /home/myUser/

Comment: Instead of `~` use `$HOME` and see if that works instead. Also, has the user's environment been set up at that point in time, when you use `~` (or `$HOME`)? If the user's environment has not been set up then neither will work, and you will have to use a full path. see [Difference between 'cd' and 'cd ~'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84615/difference-between-cd-and-cd)

Comment: Hmm, tried that, didn't work. But if I do cd ~ in terminal, it takes me back to home (that meas user's environment is set up ok?). It just doesn't work when used in autostart file. I added the user using sudo adduser.

Comment: Yes, at the time of autostart, depending on the point of start up/login where it is called, the environment might not be set fully. Not sure. Have a look on Unix Stack Exchange for an answer, maybe? That would be more relevant. [This link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174314/start-script-on-boot-up/174331#174331) might be a good starting point, and the other links in the right hand column of that page